# What is the unattend.txt entry to install DFS Replication Diagnostic and Configuration Tools?

Tags: windows-server-2003, dfs, unattended

I'm trying to make an unattend.txt-style file to use with sysocmgr.exe to verify certain Windows 2003 R2 components are uninstalled.

I've been able to find most of them, but I can't find any reference to the proper [Components] entry for "DFS Replication Diagnostic and Configuration Tools." The only two entries I have seen for DFS are DFSR and DFSRSUI, which are for different components.